# using a function turns a float into null?

Tags: php

I am quite surprised that in the code below, the first var_dump outputs null while the second outputs the correct value (0.8215). How can I fix this ?

Looking at similar questions, this kind of problem seems to come from either :

-a too old version of php (as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25161201/variable-assignment-of-anonymous-function-returns-null)) but I'm using php 5.6.

-forgetting to put a return in a function (as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16915641/why-below-function-returning-me-null-instead-of-1) or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31757484/php-function-returning-null-instead-of-array)), but I do have returns in my functions.

```
<?php

$ab_coefficients=array(
     1=>array( 0.9855 , 0.8678 ),
     2=>array( 0.9315 , 0.8215 )
);


function a_coefficient($k) {return($ab_coefficients[$k][0]);}
function b_coefficient($k) {return($ab_coefficients[$k][1]);}

var_dump($ab_coefficients[2][1]);
var_dump(b_coefficient(2));


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your functions are in parallel scopes from the global scope, to fix this, you can do 1 of 2 things. either pass in the `$ab_coefficients` array to the functions, or you can tell the function to read that variable from the global scope.

**Parameters:** *(better option)*

```
<?php

$ab_coefficients=array(
     1=>array( 0.9855 , 0.8678 ),
     2=>array( 0.9315 , 0.8215 )
);


function a_coefficient($ab_coefficients, $k) {return($ab_coefficients[$k][0]);}
function b_coefficient($ab_coefficients, $k) {return($ab_coefficients[$k][1]);}

var_dump($ab_coefficients[2][1]);
var_dump(b_coefficient($ab_coefficients, 2));


?>
```

**Global:**

```
<?php

$ab_coefficients=array(
     1=>array( 0.9855 , 0.8678 ),
     2=>array( 0.9315 , 0.8215 )
);


function a_coefficient($k) {global $ab_coefficients;return($ab_coefficients[$k][0]);}
function b_coefficient($k) {global $ab_coefficients;return($ab_coefficients[$k][1]);}

var_dump($ab_coefficients[2][1]);
var_dump(b_coefficient(2));


?>
```

Comment: Isn't it an exaggeration to say that the "parameters" version is always better ? In my project the "ab_coefficients" is intended to stay "global" and fixed all the time. Also, it seems a little silly to create a function that does such an infinitesimal job instead of simply not creating it and writing $ab_coefficients[$k][1] where it is needed.

Comment: [Why the Global State is Evil](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil)

Comment: aah I'm starting to see your point ... thanks for the references

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to a [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) issue. The `$ab_coefficients` array does not exist inside the functions as it is declared outside of them. A simple way to fix this is to include the line `global $ab_coefficients;` inside the functions as such:

```
function a_coefficient($k) {
    global $ab_coefficients;
    return($ab_coefficients[$k][0]);
}
function b_coefficient($k) {
    global $ab_coefficients;
    return($ab_coefficients[$k][1]);
}
```

This will make the variable available inside the function.